# Beautifully looking little geometry/trigonometry problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

Given triangle ABC, a,b,c as its sides, p is a half perimeter, such that $\dfrac{p-a}{11}=\dfrac{p-b}{12}=\dfrac{p-c}{13}$.

We need to find $(\tan\dfrac{A}{2})^2$

(A)$\dfrac{143}{432}$  B)$\dfrac{13}{33}$ C)$\dfrac{11}{39}$ D)$\dfrac{12}{37}$

I've tried to substitute the area of the triangle as $S=(1/2)(ab\sin C)=(1/2)(ac\sin B)=(1/2)(bc\sin A)$ and I know that $(\tan A/2)^2=(1-\cos A)/(1+\cos A)$ And some other formulas, but how is $\tan A/2$  derived from the given?

Sorry, the problem's given was confused, p is half-perimeter.

Comment: for what stands $P$ here?

Comment: $\sin(A)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ with $t=\tan(A/2)$ will help here. Also, from the equations, $(a,b,c)=k(7,6,5), k>0$ and Heron's formula for area of a triangle is $A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}=\frac{1}{2}bc\sin(A)$ with $s=P$

Comment: -.-, whatever, the basic idea will be the same

Comment: @HaipingYang  Thanks! what do you mean by (a,b,c)?

Comment: @ Jackie Poehler, means a=7k, b=6k, c=5k, however this is not true anymore since P is not the perimeter, but you can still solve the system of equations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let:  $$x=\dfrac{p-a}{11}=\dfrac{p-b}{12}=\dfrac{p-c}{13}$$

Thus, $11x+12x+13x=3p-(a+b+c)$, and so $36x=p$.

Denoting $r$ as inradius and $\Delta$ as area, we that:
$$r=\frac{\Delta}{s}=\frac{\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}}{p}=\sqrt{\frac{11\cdot 12\cdot 13\cdot x^3}{36x}}$$

And:
$$\tan^2\frac{A}2=\frac{r^2}{(p-a)^2}=\frac{11\cdot 12\cdot 13\cdot x^2}{36\cdot (11x)^2}=  { ...}$$

As to why $\tan\frac{A}2=\frac{r}{p-a}$, look at this diagram, and ask if you have any further doubts :)
[image]

Comment: This is awesome. Clear to me now. Thanks!